# How to sort some XML elements according to their dependencies, by using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, sorting

I would like to sort the following XML file:

```
<root>
  <element name="a" depends="b,c" />
  <element name="b" depends="c" />
  <element name="c" />
</root>
```

With this result:

```
<root>
  <element name="c" />
  <element name="b" depends="c" />
  <element name="a" depends="b,c" />
</root>
```

My dependencies can be modeled by using a tree (no cycle).
depends="b,c" means depends on both  b and c.
I'm asking the good way to do this by using XSLT. Perhaps, do you have some ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Unless you use XSLT 2.0 where you could use e.g. `tokenize(@depends, ',')` I don't think stuffing the depends values into an attribute is a good design if you want to process them with XSLT. So if you want to use XSLT consider to use instead a list of child elements `<dependency-list><item>b</item><item>c</item></dependency>`. As for the output you want, can you explain in more detail what `depends="b,c"` describes? Does it simply say "depends on b and c" or does it also describe an order?

Comment: I have edited my answer and am now providing an XSLT 2.0 transformation that really solves the problem (working correctly with your second provided XML document). Thanks again for the good question.

Answer (score 1):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <root>
      <xsl:call-template name="directDependents"/>
     </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="directDependents">
  <xsl:param name="pCore" as="element()*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNewDependents" select=
  "/*/element
       [not(. intersect $pCore)
      and
       not(tokenize(@depends, ',')[not(. = $pCore/@name)])
       ]
  "/>

  <xsl:if test="$vNewDependents">
   <xsl:sequence select="$vNewDependents"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="directDependents">
    <xsl:with-param name="pCore" select="$pCore | $vNewDependents"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the (second) provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <element name="a" depends="b" />
    <element name="b" depends="c" />
    <element name="c" />
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <element name="c"/>
   <element name="b" depends="c"/>
   <element name="a" depends="b"/>
</root>
```

**Update**: Here is a more "XSLT 2.0 looking solution" (untested -- will correct any errors when I'm back home):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <root>
      <xsl:sequence select="my:directDependents(/..)"/>
     </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:directDependents">
  <xsl:param name="pCore" as="element()*"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $vNewDependents in
    /*/element
           [not(. intersect $pCore)
          and
           not(tokenize(@depends, ',')[not(. = $pCore/@name)])
           ]
    return
      if($vNewDependents)
        then
         (
          $vNewDependents,
          my:directDependents($pCore | $vNewDependents)
          )
        else ()
  "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have been looking for this. The first solution (with named template) gave me the following error (with Saxon9HE):
´Error on line 17 of dependency-sort.xsl:
  FORG0006: Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two or more
 items
  starting with a string
  at xsl:call-template name="directDependents" (file:/E:/Peter//dependency-sort.xsl#11)
  in built-in template rule
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported´

The line for which the error is reported is the one containing xsl:variable

Comment: @PeterHofman, Most likely you are using a buggy XSLT processor. Works fine using both Saxon 9.1.08 and 9.5.01EE. Or there is an error in *your* code -- which we have not seen.

Comment: I use the stylesheet from your solution, with Saxon9HE latest version. The error occurs when @depends contains a comma separated list of dependencies (like in the original question), which I expected to work since the provided code contains tokenize(@depends,',').

Comment: After changing the input to match the second XML input described above, it worked ok, but unfortunately it does not seem to support indirect circular references.

Comment: @PeterHofman, What do you mean by "indirect circular references"? Look at a similar example in the last module of my Pluralsight training course -- the code there catches cycles and throws an error.

Comment: I have no subscription for Pluralsight, so I cannot look at the example.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I will probably post a new question, since it does not seem very handy to work in comments here.

Comment: @PeterHofman, Definitely. Just let me know when you post your question.

Comment: @PeterHofman, Pluralsight gives everyone a 10 day, 200 minutes free trial.