# How to sort XML elements based on their predecessors

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I'm trying to sort and XML elements using XSL, something similar to this post:
[How to sort some XML elements according to their dependencies, by using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553288/how-to-sort-some-xml-elements-according-to-their-dependencies-by-using-xslt/17665882#17665882) , but in my case I have the following xml:

```
<root>
    <element name="a" predecessor="x">
    <children>
       <element name="b" predecessor="c"/>
       <element name="c" predecessor="a"/>
       <element name="d" predecessor="b"/>
    </children>
    </element>
</root>
```

The expected output would be:

```
<root>
    <element name="a" predecessor="x">
    <children>
       <element name="c" predecessor="a"/>
       <element name="b" predecessor="c"/>
       <element name="d" predecessor="b"/>
    </children>
    </element>
</root>
```

Can you help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this recursive approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | *">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="children" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element[@predecessor=current()/../@name]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../element[@predecessor=current()/@name]" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <element name="a" predecessor="x">
        <children>
            <element name="c" predecessor="a"/>
            <element name="b" predecessor="c"/>
            <element name="d" predecessor="b"/>
        </children>
    </element>
</root>
```